# Copy files with the same name but in different dirs into a new dir while renaming them

Tags: command-line, terminal, rename, file-copy

I have the following directory structure:

```
top_dir
   |________AA
             |_______f1.json
             |_______f2.json
   |________BB
             |_______f1.json
             |_______f2.json
   |________CC
             |_______f1.json
             |_______f2.json
```

I would like to write a script / command line command to get the following structure

```
new_dir
       |_______f1_AA.json
       |_______f2_AA.json
       |_______f1_BB.json
       |_______f2_BB.json
       |_______f1_CC.json
       |_______f2_CC.json
```

I tried reading into some solutions for renaming files and copying moving files with the same. However, I am not yet able to solve this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop:

```
mkdir /path_to/new_dir
cd /path_to/top_dir

for i in */*.json; do 
  cp "$i" "/path_to/new_dir/$(basename "$i" .json)_$(dirname "$i").json"
done
```

- `$(basename "$i" .json)` prints the filename without suffix, e.g. `f1`
- `$(dirname "$i")` prints the directory name, e.g. `AA`

Answer (score 0):

With Larry Wall's `perl-rename` (a.k.a. `rename` on Debian/Ubuntu and `prename` on RHEL/Centos):

```
perl-rename -n 's:([^/]+)/(.+).json:path/to/new/dir/$2_$1.json:' */*.json
```

Replace `-n` by `-v` for actual execution.